# Jibx: Integrate base class output into extending class output

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I have this class model:

```
abstract class A {
    int a;
}

class B extends A {
    int b;
}

class C extends B {
    int c;
}
```

And I'd like to get jibx to output this XML:

```
<B b=1 a=0>
    <children>
        <C c=2 b=1 a=0/>        
    </children>
</B>
```

I have this binding xml:

```
<binding>
    <mapping class="A" abstract="true">
        <value name="a" field="a" style="attribute" usage="optional"/>      
        <collection field="children" type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    </mapping>
    <mapping name="B" class="B" extends="A">
        <value name="b" field="b" style="attribute" usage="optional"/>
        <structure map-as="A"/>
    </mapping>
    <mapping name="C" class="C" extends="B">
        <value name="c" field="c" style="attribute" usage="optional"/>
        <structure map-as="B"/>
    </mapping>
</binding>
```

However I keep getting artifacts like this:

```
<C c=2>
    <B b=1 a=0>
        <children>
            ...
        </children>
    </B>
</C>
```

As temporary solution I've changed my inheritance structure to have AbstractB and B extends AbstractB and C extends AbstractB, but it really annoys me to have to redesign my class because of jibx.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Edit:
As a bonus question - how do you use code/decode java.util.Map with Jibx? I know it can't be done natively (would be glad to be disproved!) but what would you do to code Map (no strings). Please note we're not using jibx-extras.jar, so solutions should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IMHO it feels kind of normal to get C as parent (in XML sense) of B, because **C contains the information of B** (from wich it inherits) **and its own information aside**, but B doesn't know about those C-specific information right ?

To make it clearer: it B is **Bird** and C is **Chicken**. Chicken is a Bird, so C inherits form B, OK. But in XML format, would store :

```
<Bird color="brown">
    <Chicken label="Kentucky-fried" />
</Bird>
```

or

```
<Chicken label="Kentucky-fried"> <!-- chicken-specific information -->
    <Bird color="brown" /> <!-- "birdy" part of the chicken -->
</Chicken>
```

?

So on the model point of view, it seems logical to me...
And I didn't find a way of achieving the opposite in the [binding tutorial](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/tutorial/binding-mappings.html#inherit), sorry.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but that answer doesn't really solves my problem.